# Are there tools that can spot errors like this one?

Tags: python

I found the following mistake in my code this week:

```
import datetime

d = datetime.date(2010,9,24)
if d.isoweekday == 5:
    pass
```

Yes, it should be d.isoweekday() instead.

I know, if I had had a test-case for this I would have been saved.
Comparing a function with 5 is not very useful. Oh, I'm not blaming Python for this.

My question: Are there tools that can spot errors like this one?

Comment: "if I had had a test-case for this".  Isn't that the answer to your question?  "Write a unit test."

Comment: @S.Lott I covered myself for this answer. So, no. :)

Comment: You're missing the point.  Given (a) the absence of a test and (b) the answers you have, you're going to have to start writing tests.

Comment: If I only had had enough reputation to edit that question, I could have had had the ability to fix the typo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As an *alternative*, most Python projects are **unit tested** and system tested. If you have both (or even just unit tests) you'll find your problem along with pretty much any other issue.

As *dekomote* said, this is syntaxically valid. Python is *not* statically typed so this cannot be caught as an error. At most it could be a warning.

EDIT: Python is strongly typed just the type is checked at run time.

Comment: -1 python is strongly typed. It is not _statically_ typed. This is not a small distinction. Further, it shouldn't even be a warning because the comparison is perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Well it doesn't change much unless a tool is capable of emulating an execution without running the program. Else it could only be a guess.

Comment: +1 for being the only one in the answers to recommend unit testing (S. Lott is on it in the comments)

Comment: Just because it's perfectly valid doesn't mean it isn't worthy of a warning.  In C, `if (x=false)` is perfectly valid as well, but we're all glad the compiler warns us when it shows up in our code.

Comment: @Darryl: C is statically typed. Doesn't mean there cannot be a warning but that warning may be incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Check out **[pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857)** it may be able to get that. It does find many errors.

Comment: That's because there is no error here. d.isoweekday == 5 is a valid statement.

Comment: @dekomote It didn't work the way Eddy intended, so it's a user error, which is what linters are supposed to catch. Not that they can catch everything, but it's incorrect to say there was no error.

Comment: @dekomote: you're missing the point of pychecker and pylint.  They aren't for finding invalid Python: they are for finding mistakes that people make.  For example, they can tell you that you import a module but never use it, which is perfectly valid Python, but probably not what you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is not an error in python per se because in Python, the functions are **callable objects**. You can make any object callable by implementing `__call__`. So d.isoweekday == 5 is valid statement. This will be False.

As for other errors, i suggest checking out pyflakes - http://divmod.org/trac/wiki/DivmodPyflakes